# code in comment reflected in run

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Learning development block in Drupal 8, surprised that the code in comment block was pickup when running.

When I change the block name here: admin_label = @Translation("Hello block"),

The system will change, but the code is in comment.  Just wonder how come comments are reflected.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\hello_world\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Hello' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "hello_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Hello block"),
 * )
 */
class HelloBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments above your Class are not just comments, they are actually annotations, used to define certain properties of Classes in Drupal 8.

Thus when you make changes, it reflects.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/annotation/8.2.x